# Updating many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a many-to-many relationship between `Department` objects and `Grade` objects, I am trying to update the `Department` by assigning a `Grade`. This is my update method:

```
public void UpdateDep(CommonLayer.Depratment UpDep)
{
    CommonLayer.Depratment CheckDepartment = this.getDepartment(UpDep.Department_GUID);
    this.Entities.Entry(CheckDepartment).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpDep);
    this.Entities.SaveChanges();

}
```

`UpDep` has the `Grade` id value but `CheckDepartment` is not being updated. No errors are being shown. I cannot understand what is wrong, as I have done this many times before.

Comment: I am not using a model i am passing the ids from the view through the controller to another method which adds the grade to the department and updating by calling this method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not?

```
public void UpdateDep(CommonLayer.Depratment UpDep)
    {
        CommonLayer.Depratment CheckDepartment = this.getDepartment(UpDep.Department_GUID);
        this.Entities.Entry(CheckDepartment).CurrentValues.SetValues(UpDep);
        this.Entities.Entry(CheckDepartment).State = EntityState.Changed; 
        this.Entities.SaveChanges();

    }
```

notice the state.

Comment: what about this line `this.Entities.Entry(CheckDepartment).State = EntityState.Modified;`